# How to apply a programme to all values in a list simultaneously

Tags: arduino-uno

I'm attempting to turn on a set of LED's one at a time and then switch them all off at the same time, I am stuck however on turning them off at the same time.

That is my code:

```
int ledpins[] = {2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}; //creates a list of the pins in use

void setup() {
  for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++){
    pinMode(ledpins[i], OUTPUT);  // iterates over the list led pins from the 0 pin to the pins before the eigth
  }  
}

void loop() {
  for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++){
    digitalWrite(ledpins[i], HIGH); // turns all the pins of one at a time
  }

  delay(100); //when all on will wait 100 ms
  digitalWrite(ledpins[0,7], LOW); //turns off all the leds at once
  delay(100);
}
```

The annotations are for my own understanding.
I just need help turning all the LED's off at once which I dont know the command for.

Answer (score 3):

You have already done it twice, why are you struggling the third time?

```
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++){
  digitalWrite(ledpins[i], HIGH); // turns all the pins of one at a time
}
```

> // turns all the pins of one at a time

Except that it is happening so fast you can't see then doing it individually. So just do the same but set them to LOW:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++){
  digitalWrite(ledpins[i], LOW); // turns all the pins off one at a time
}
```

Now you might want to add a delay into the loop that turns them on so you can see them turn on individually instead of all at once:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++){
  digitalWrite(ledpins[i], HIGH); // turns all the pins of one at a time
  delay(50);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is another approach that is to use direct port manipulation. It is a lot faster than using `digitalWrite` in the sense that it requires less clock cycles to execute and allows you to change one port at a time (the UNO has 3 ports called D, B and C). You can find an introduction to port manipulation on this page: https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/PortManipulation

Here is an example that toggles the LED you chose:

```
void setup()
{
    DDRD |= B11111100; // Pin 2 to 7 as outputs
    DDRB |= B00000011; // Pin 8 to 9 as outputs
}


void loop()
{
    // Pin 2 to 7 HIGH
    PORTD |= ( 1<<2 ) | ( 1<<3 ) | ( 1<<4 ) | ( 1<<5 ) | ( 1<<6 ) | ( 1<<7 );
    // Pin 8 to 9 HIGH
    PORTB |= ( 1<<0 ) | ( 1<<1 );

    _delay_ms( 500 );

    // Pin 2 to 7 LOW
    PORTD &= ~( 1<<2 ) & ~( 1<<3 ) & ~( 1<<4 ) & ~( 1<<5 ) & ~( 1<<6 ) & ~( 1<<7 );
    // Pin 8 to 9 LOW
    PORTB &= ~( 1<<0 ) & ~( 1<<1 );

    _delay_ms( 500 );
}
```